# Problem with 3d nonlinear system

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-system

I am trying to find solution for this system of nonlinear equations.

$f(x) = 0$

[image: f(x)]

- a) Calculate all the zero`s in the system (mannualy)
- b) Find the Jacobioan matrix, J(x). (Notice that J(x) is singular for
  x(3) = 0)
- c) Consider independent two starting solutions:   
   1) x(0) = {-0.01, 
  -0.01, -0.01}T   
   2) x(0) = {-0.1, -0.1, -0.1}T

I stucked here:
$$\begin{cases}
x_1^5 \pm x_2^3 =0 \\[2ex] 
x_1^2 * x_2 * (\pm 1) = 0 \\[2ex] 
x_3 = \pm 1
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Interesting. But what is your question ?

Comment: I'm going to change some things to prevent confusion between the variable $x$ and the functions $x_1$,$x_2$, and $x_3$. What you have is  $$f(\vec x)=\begin{bmatrix} x_1^5+x_2^3x_3^4+1\\ x_1^2x_2x_3\\ x_3^4-1 \end{bmatrix}$$ Where

Comment: is this your system: $$x_1^5+x_2^3x_3^4+1=0$$ and $$x_1^2x_2x_3=0$$ and $$x_3^4-1=0$$?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures cannot be searched and are inaccessible to those using screen readers.

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Alright! What I am going to do is give you an example of a problem similar to the one you are doing. That way you can understand what exactly you are trying to do, but without actually doing your homework for you. Without further ado, let $f: \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$ such that 
$$f(\vec x):= \begin{bmatrix}
2x_1^2-x_2x_3-8\\
x^2_1x_2+2x_1x_2x_3+x_2x_3^2\\
x_3^2-4
\end{bmatrix}$$

a) find $\vec x$ such that  $f(\vec x)=\vec 0$.

b) find the Jacobian matrix of $f$

a) we have a set of solutions where 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
2x_1^2-x_2x_3-8\\
x^2_1x_2+2x_1x_2x_3+x_2x_3^2\\
x_3^2-4
\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$
Solving independently we have that 
$$x_3=\pm 2,$$ 
$$x_2(x_1+x_3)^2=0,$$
and 
$$2x_1^2-x_2x_3=8.$$

If $x_2 =0$. Then from the third equation we have $x_1^2=8/2=4$. So $x_1=\pm 2$.

If $(x_1+x_3)=0$. Then $x_3=-x_1=\pm 2$, and from the third equation we have 
$$2x_1^2+x_1x_2=8$$
$\Rightarrow$
$$x_1(2x_1+x_2)=8.$$
As $x_1=\pm 2$ this implies that 
$$x_2=\pm 4-\pm 4=0$$
So for the zero's we have 
$$\begin{bmatrix}2\\0\\2\end{bmatrix},\:\begin{bmatrix}2\\0\\-2\end{bmatrix},\:\begin{bmatrix}-2\\0\\2\end{bmatrix},\:\mathrm{and}\;\:\begin{bmatrix}-2\\0\\-2\end{bmatrix}$$

b) The Jacobian matrix is the matrix of partial derivatives. Hence,
$$J_f=\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1}&\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_2}&\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_3}\\
\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_1}&\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2}&\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_3}\\
\frac{\partial f_3}{\partial x_1}&\frac{\partial f_3}{\partial x_2}&\frac{\partial f_3}{\partial x_3}
\end{bmatrix}$$

Since $f_1=2x_1^2-x_2x_3-8$, $f_2=x^2_1x_2+2x_1x_2x_3+x_2x_3^2$, and $f_3=x_3^2-4$, this implies that
$$J_f=\begin{bmatrix}
4x_1&-x_3&-x_2\\
x_2x_3^2&(x_1+x_3)^2&x_1^2x_2\\
0&0&2x_3
\end{bmatrix}$$

As for c) all you've asked to do is consider those vector points. There is literally no question. This is like asking me to "Observe your keyboard for a minute". Okay, I've observed my keyboard for a minute now what?

Comment: In my example i have tried this:

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
x_1^5+x_2^3*x_3^4+1=0\\ 
x_1^2*x_2*x_3=0 \\ 
x_3^4-1=0 
\end{aligned} 
\right. 
$$

now from this i can see that
x3 = +- 1;
and for seccond line i have

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
x_1^5+x_2^3=-1\\ 
x_1^2*x_2=0 \\ 
x_3=+-1
\end{aligned} 
\right. 
$$

and i stucked here...

Comment: @Bambus Lets say you had one nonlinear equation $f(x)=3x^2-2x+4$ How would you find the $\mathrm{roots}$ of this equation?

Comment: $f(x) = \frac{-b \pm (b^2 - 4ac)}{2a}$     
using this i`ve got:   
$x = -\frac {1}{3} - \sqrt{13}/{3}$   
 
and   

$x = -\frac {1}{3} + \sqrt{13}/{3}$

Comment: Very good. You used the quadratic formula to help you solve the problem. However your answer is a bit off, since $\sqrt{b^2-4ac}=\sqrt{4-4(12)}=2\sqrt{-11}$ which is imaginary. Sorry for the trick question. Here's a better question: what are the roots of $f(x)=x^3-5x^2+4x-20$?

Comment: I found this solution because i dont know how to write it correctly here. Here is the link:   https://www.mathway.com/popular-problems/Precalculus/428024   I just left it here: x=5 and x = +- Sqrt (-4)

Comment: $f(x)=0=x^3-5x^2+4x-20$ we can then factor out an $x-5$ from the function giving us $0=(x-5)(x^2+4)$ from here you can immediately see that the roots are $5, \pm\sqrt{-4}$ but the key here is that either $(x-5)=0$ or $(x^2+4)=0$.   Just like for my example I had that either $x_1+x_3=0$ or $x_2=0$, Do you see something similar in your problem?

Comment: $$\begin{cases}
x_1^5 \pm x_2^3 =0 \\[2ex] 
x_1^2 * x_2 * (\pm 1) = 0 \\[2ex] 
x_3 = \pm 1
\end{cases}
$$
I stucked here..

Comment: Close, you're stuck at $$\left\{ \begin{array}  x x^5_1\pm x^3_2=-1\\ x^2_1\cdot x_2\cdot (\pm 1)=0\\x_3=\pm 1\end{array}\right.$$ Lets, look at the second equation $0=\pm(x^2_1\cdot x_2)$. What can discern from that equation? Try substituting $x_1=a$ and $x_2=b$ if your still having difficulty.